# .pubxml file format to add data debugging information specification - "embedded" or "portable" when publishing project

Tags: .net, linux, debugging, arm, publish

We develop on Yocto linux (Debian 10 based) with .net 5
It needs to publish project in different architecture - linux-arm64 and include information for debugging in "embedded" or "portable" way.
However in Visual Studio 2019 this options have been removed from GUI, and only possible to set editing manually the .pubxml file that was generated by visard.

I have found the configuration that worked with running the code on remote system, but not with debugging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>E:\DEPLOY\AVIDAMO\_Yocto_Linux_Publish</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Could you help me with data on .pubxml file format options, would be good to publish with ftp, or directly with ssh...?
And specifically how to add an option for debugging information "embedded" or "portable"?